# cygwin: I can't create a file named "d.a.z"

Tags: cygwin, filenames

I don't know what the problem could be, but I can't name a file "d.a.z", when I do an ls on the system, the filename becomes:   X~=@l9q5

Does anyone know why that particular filename would do that?

Comment: Could you give us a sample of how you are creating the file?

Comment: `touch d.a.z` works for me here. (Great nick, by the way. Icelandic, or just pretending?)

Comment: @MLF: vi d.a.z   type in some data ... save it...   I've been through the alphabet prior to it, e.g. d.a.a, d.a.b, ... d.a.x, d.a.y, d.b.a, d.b.b.. etc.

Comment: @WarrenYoung  Norwegian + gender + read slashdot daily and feeling like that's close enough to get away with it.  =)

Comment: I just tried your `vi` method on a different Cygwin install, under a different version of Windows. It still works here. I suspect [BLODA](http://cygwin.com/acronyms/#BLODA).

Comment: Okay, good to know that other people are not having this problem, cause it seems like a crazy thing.  I just tried it again in a different directory and d.a.z ls's to d.a    Very weird

Comment: The fact that the symptom changes in a different directory makes this feel more like the [MICROS~1 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32) than BLODA. It affects FAT32 filesystems. All of my tests have been on NTFS.

Comment: The only Windows app that I know about that cares about the .z extension in WinRar.  anyway, thank you for the infoz